# Como excluir elementos dois array numpy relacionados?

Tags: python, array, numpy

Meu x e meu y pra plotar são:

```
x0_n125n25matriz= [ 3472.222  3501.157  3530.092  3559.028  3587.963  3616.898  3645.833
  3674.768  3732.639  3761.574  3819.444  3848.379  3877.315  3906.25
  3935.185  3964.12   3993.055  4021.991  4050.926  4079.861  4108.796
  4137.731  4166.667  4195.602  4224.537  4253.472  1938.657  1967.593
  1996.528  2025.463  2054.398  2083.333  2112.268  2141.204  2170.139
  2199.074  2228.009  2459.491  2488.426  2517.361  2546.296  2575.231
  2604.167  2633.102  2662.037  2690.972  2719.907  2777.778  2806.713
  2835.648  2864.583  2893.518  2922.454  2951.389  2980.324  3009.259
  3038.194  3067.13   3125.     3153.935  3182.87   3211.805  3240.741
  3269.676  3298.611  3327.546  3356.481  3385.417  3414.352  3443.287]
```

```
y15_n0matriz= [-0.16542411 -0.16646451 -0.15804609 -0.16922809 -0.16509723 -0.17315663
 -1.         -0.16794772 -0.18579247 -0.1910353  -1.         -0.17504794
 -0.17359474 -0.1910353  -0.23110434 -0.21745199 -0.20903377 -0.20411454
 -0.14195609 -0.12418465 -0.02185758 -0.06863125 -0.05559483 -1.
 -0.00618082  0.31784786 -0.03661292 -0.0307183  -0.05644441 -0.08442226
 -0.06980404 -0.10472111 -0.0879587  -0.12047211 -0.1447231  -0.13637791
 -0.17421431 -0.2750271  -0.28981587 -0.29746496 -0.29663548 -0.29411292
 -0.26879031 -1.         -1.         -1.         -1.         -0.26504059
 -0.25901137 -1.         -1.         -1.         -1.         -1.
 -0.23680369 -0.22844707 -0.22335351 -0.21784316 -0.18085159 -0.16489683
 -0.16492188 -0.16724017 -0.16639032 -0.16230818 -0.16707027 -0.16008367
 -0.15638411 -0.17402684 -0.19244248 -0.18580143]
```

Do y, eu preciso excluir esses -1 da matriz e excluir tbm na matriz x os valores correspondentes à esse índice do -1 em y, pra não dar erro de dimensão pra plotar . Fiz assim:

```
x0_n125n25valores=[]
for i in x0_n125n25:
    if i!=0:
        x0_n125n25valores.append(i)

x0_n125n25matriz=np.asarray(x0_n125n25valores)
print(x0_n125n25matriz)
print(x0_n125n25matriz.shape)

y15_n0valores = []
for i in y15_n0:
    if i>=-1 and i<1:
        y15_n0valores.append(i)

y15_n0matriz=np.asarray(y15_n0valores)

y15_n0matrizteste=[]                       ############### ERRO NESSA PARTE
for i in range(0,len(y15_n0matriz)):
    if y15_n0matriz[i]>-1.00000000e+00:
        y15_n0matrizteste.append(y15_n0matriz[i])
    if y15_n0matriz[i]==-1.00000000e+00:
        x0_n125n25matriznovo= np.delete(x0_n125n25matriz,i)
y15_n0matriznovo2 = np.asarray(y15_n0matrizteste)
print(y15_n0matriznovo2)
print(y15_n0matriznovo2.shape)
```

No print vi que excluí os -1 corretamente da matriz y mas não excluiu os valores correspondentes em x. Alguém tem alguma ideia do pq? Tentei de outro jeito mas tbm não deu:

```
for i in range(0,len(y15_n0matriz)):
    if y15_n0matriz[i]==-1.00000000e+00:
        y15_n0matriznovo = np.delete(y15_n0matriz,i)
        x0_n125n25matriznovo= np.delete(x0_n125n25matriz,i)
```

Desse jeito aí não excluiu ponto nenhum. Não sei pq, help!

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Antes de mais nada: "arrays" de numpy são diferentes de "listas" de Python - não dá para alterar o tamanho delas de forma simples: não funciona `del array[i]` para apagar o elemento de índice "i" de uma array. Como listas são parte da linguagem, e é importante entender o algoritmo pra isso, em vez de só a "mágica" do numpy, abordo esse modo primeiro.

Uma boa ideia em programação é que coisas simples sejam simples - então - mesmo que você precise em algum momento usar esses nomes de variáveis complicados, fica ruim de ficar colocando em "if" e "for" o nome "x0_n125n25valores".

Felizmente, o conceito de funções em programação ajuda justamente com isso - dentro de uma função usamos nomes genéricos - daí você chama a função com suas variáveis de nome complicado. (eu também sugeriria não usar nomes complicados pra começar -se precisa marcar as séries de dados com "n12n25" pra saber que é isso mesmo, vale a pena colocar tudo dentro de um dicionário - mas só se ficar mais fácil pra quem for usar o código ler).

VOltando ao problema principal: 
quero percorrer duas sequências, e onde houver um "-1" na segunda sequência, apagar o elemento de lá, e o elemento correspondente na sequencia principal.

Em Python, o `for` sempre percorre os elementos de uma sequência - e podemos usar a chamada `enumerate`, para além do elemento, termos também o índice. ALém disso, em qualquer linguagem, se você for alterar o comprimento de uma array enquanto está iterando sobre ela, vai ter problemas - então um pattern interessante é fazer uma iteração anotando os índices dos elementos a apagar,e uma segunda interação apagando aqueles índices:

```py
def remove_elementos(referencia, espelho, valor=-1):
    remover = []
    for indice, elemento in enumerate(referencia):
        if elemento == valor:
            remover.append(indice)
    for indice in reversed(remover):
        del referencia[indice]
        del espelho[indice]

    return referencia, espelho
```

E aí , é só chamar essas funções com suas listas contendo dados - elas serão alteradas *inplace*, e você nem precisa se preocupar em atribuir o valor de retorno.

Depois que você tenha entendido esse algoritmo, aí sim podemos passar a:

## Filtrar usando o numpy

Já com o numpy, temos acesso a várias ferramentas que não fazem parte do "núcleo" do Python - principalemnte a capacidade de aplicar operações a cada item de um array, baseado no conteúdo de outro array, ou um escalar.

Por exemplo, para filtrar eleentos de um array, podemos passar uma outra sequencia como *índice* de um array (em vez de passar um índice numérico) - se a sequência passada tiver valores "True" e "False", apenas os elementos que correspondem a "True" são retornados - é importante visualizar isso:

```py
In [78]: a = np.array([0,1,2,3,4,5])                                                                                                 

In [79]: a                                                                                                                           
Out[79]: array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])

In [80]: b = [True, False, True, True, True, True]                                                                                   

In [81]: a[b]                                                                                                                        
Out[81]: array([0, 2, 3, 4, 5])
```

Observe como a saída de `a[b]` excluiu o elemento na posição "1" - que é onde estava o "False" na minha sequência b (b no caso é uma lista -tanto listas quanto arrays do numpy são "sequências" e funcionam).

Daí juntamos isso com a capacidade do numpy de, ao fazer qualquer operação de uma array com um escalar, ele gera um outro array com o resultado da operação. E que a "operação" no caso, pode ser uma comparação (==):

```
In [83]: x = np.array([0, 1, 2, 3, 4, 5])                                                                                            

In [84]: y = np.array([0, 1, -1, 3, 4, -1])                                                                                          

In [85]: filtro = y == -1                                                                                                            

In [86]: filtro                                                                                                                      
Out[86]: array([False, False,  True, False, False,  True])

In [87]: filtro = y != -1                                                                                                            

In [88]: filtro                                                                                                                      
Out[88]: array([ True,  True, False,  True,  True, False])
```

Pronto - sabendo essas duas coisas, você consegue filtrar os elementos dos seus dados originais. Só lembrar que a operaçao de filtro (o penúltimo exemplo, acima), gera um *novo* array, não é feito "inplace" - e guardar o resultado disso na variável de volta:

```py
filtro = y15_n0matriz != -1
y15_n0matriz = y15_n0matriz[filtro]
x0_n125n25matriz = x0_n125n25matriz[filtro]
```

Pronto!